# Inserting into database using ajax , 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my html I have a simple ajax that's inside a function that gets called on a button press. I want the php script that's called to insert the javascript variable sent into a database.

```
var myval = 'testuser'; // generated by PHP

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'testfile.php',
              data: {'variable': myval},
            });
```

In my testfile.php I have tried numerous things to insert into the database but with no luck. I know that ajax is working because doing just the bellow works fine with no errors.

```
<?php

$myval = $_POST['variable'];
echo $myval;

?>
```

I tried doing this bellow first with global variables. Then even tried putting in the values manually and I kept getting the 500 error even though I have the exact same code in another script (not being called by ajax) and it works fine.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. test_user, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

So I tried opening it a different way.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','username,'pass','newdb');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

and that worked fine. However putting in the global variables causes it not to work.

Then I tried to insert to a table.

```
  INSERT INTO send (user_id)
  VALUES ($myval);
```

and I get a 500 error again.

I try accessing the php file directly (testsite.com/testfile.php) and get a blank page. Viewing source gives me nothing.

What am I doing wrong as to keep getting these errors?

Comment: pretty sure `data: {'variable': myval},` should be  `data: {variable: myval},`

Comment: I'll try changing that but even when I put a string into VALUES I still get an error. So there must be a problem somewhere else, right?

Comment: I've provided some code. Please check it out and comment back if you still need help. There might be a problem if you're query looked like this `INSERT INTO send (user_id)
  VALUES ($myval);` without the other syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
   <?php

    //Enter your database connection details here.
    $host = 'localhost'; //HOST NAME.
    $db_name = 'dbname'; //Database Name
    $db_username = 'root'; //Database Username
    $db_password = ''; //Database Password

    try
    {
        $myval = $_POST['variable'];
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
        $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO send (user_id) VALUES (?)');
        $query->bindValue(1, $myval);
        $query->execute();
        echo $myval;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
    }
    ?>
```

Javascript:

```
var myval = 'testuser'; // generated by PHP

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'testfile.php',
              data: {variable: myval},
            });
```

Don't add quotes around the variable name. I've provided a php script that should work the way you want it to, comment back if you still need help.

Comment: ah ha! Worked great, thanks so much. Learned a lot from this.